# Can Blood-Kin steal freely from Orc strongholds

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am **Blood-Kin** and able to freely enter and trade in **Orc Strongholds**. However I still get the "*Steal*" message if I hover my cursor over any of the items in the Orc Stronghold. Is this normal?

The reason I ask is because doing favors for certain groups allows you to freely take low-value items from certain places without stealing. Is this never the case with Orc Strongholds? Will it always be stealing to take from an Orc Stronghold? Has anyone had a different experience where they can freely take low value items from Orc Strongholds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not about being Blood-Kin but about proving yourself stronger then the chief.

To be able to take what you want you need to talk to the chieftain of the hold and challenge him to a brawl (fist fight) with a 100gold wager. If you lose you lose 100 gold, if you win you get 100 gold and the permission to take items from the hold.

This has to be done for every hold separately but can't be done for Largashbur.

(Blood-Kin does give you access to the holds so you need to do that first to be able to challenge the chieftains.)

Comment: Wow I would not have guessed that brawling the chieftain would unlock this! Thank you. This should information be added to the wiki.

Comment: @MatthaeusGaiusCaesar: Rule of thumb: Brawling an NPC makes them friendly. Because Nords and Orcs are just like that, I guess.